# Computing regression coefficient values in OLS

Tags: regression

I have a question on testing the hypothesis that a particular regression coefficient in a simple OLS scheme with all the good assumptions is zero or not.

In particular eq 3.12, in the book by Tibshirani and coll., [*Elements of Statistical Learning*](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) defines the z-score as

$$z = \beta/\hat\sigma\sqrt{v_j}$$

My question is that given the regression coefficients are all jointly normal, how can we separate one coefficient out like that? Is that a conditional z-score assuming all others betas have a particular value?

Answer (score 5):

1. If regression coefficients are jointly normal, then single coefficient is normal. Since we want to test hypothesis only about single coefficient we use its own distribution. Why should we care what happens to other coefficients?
2. If however we want to take into account other coefficients, then we should modify the hypothesis. So for example we can test that two coefficients are zero. So the answer is no, it is not conditional z score, but it is possible to have a statistic similar to z-score involving more that one coefficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response mpiktas, here are some follow up thoughts. Forgive my ignorance! How about independence, I guess under classical OLS it is fair to say that the betas are independent, is that the case?. If yes, then the multivariate normal degenerates to individual normal distributions and then I can build any test on any single coefficient. If no, then how does one take into account the values other coefficients are taking. We cannot test a condition on a dependent variable (beta) without thinking what the other variable (beta) is doing. (...)

Comment: (...) What happens to a more complex case of lasso, where we know that betas are dependent? (copy/paste since the last sentence was lost when converting to comment)